# export all the contact details from iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to export all the contact details of iphone and uplaod to server

is that posble from Xcode or i need a 3rd  party software??

Answer (score 0):

You can export the contact to XML string and pass it to Web service.
Exporting Contacts to xml by iterating over all contact to get the details like first name , last Name , Address ... etc.
hope this be helpful.